# Конвертирование файла из jpeg в bmp

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Необходимо в программе на C++ конвертировать картинку из Jpeg в растровый BMP. Есть ли у кого нибудь исходник?

Answer (score 3):

Для кросс-платформенного решения подойдет ImageMagic или FreeImage (и то, и то поддерживает C/C++). Например, для FreeImage:

```
if (FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(FIF_JPEG, from, JPG_DEFAULT)) {  
    FreeImage_Save(FIF_BMP, bitmap, to, BMP_DEFAULT);  
    FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
}
```

А для ImageMagic можно и из командной строки:

```
%magick_home%\convert -depth 8 file.jpg file.bmp
```